# Adding elements to unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add an li to a ul using jquery and can't get it to work. I am using the following code.

I have read an XML file which is in the following format for example,

```
<Products>
    <Description>Pound</Description>
    <ProductType>CUR</ProductType>
    <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
    <Rate>1</Rate></ProductRate>
    <Description>Euro</Description>
    <ProductType>CUR</ProductType>
    <CurrencyCode>Eur</CurrencyCode>
    <Rate>1.5</Rate></ProductRate>
</Products>
```

I am trying to use jquery to create a list of the products but it keeps adding them as 1 li element and not multiple li's where list is the actual list,

I am using the following jquery

```
var $xml = $(xml);
var $list = $('#list');
$description = $xml.find("Description");
$( "#list" ).append($description.text());`
```

This reads the elements but adds them as a single li element

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Pound GBP Euro Eur
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried

```
$( "#list" ).append("<li>"+$description.text()+"</li>");
```

but this still delivers the same html.  So my question is how do I ensure they are shown as separate li elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
$description.each(function() {
    $("#list").append("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jH5D5/)

Comment: using the same XML is it possible within the each function to grab the 'rate' by doing something like 
    `$rate = $xml.find("Rate");
    $( "#list" ).append($rate.text());`

Answer (score 2):

Try to iterate through each of the elements being read:

```
$xml.find("Description").each(function(){
     $( "#list" ).append("<li>"+$(this).text()+"</li>");
});
```